How to get cookies in browser extension
I am developing a browser extension using wxt.dev and there i want to get cookies.
tried using google cookie APis but getting undefined
function getCookies(domain: any, name: any, callback: any) {
  chrome.cookie.get({ url: domain, name: name }, function (cookie: any) {
    if (callback) {
      callback(cookie.value);
    }
  });
}

getCookies("https://www.linkedin.com/", "id", function (id: any) {
  alert(id);
});


I was able to solve this


chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs: any) => {
  const url = new URL(tabs[0].url);
  chrome.cookies.getAll({ domain: url.hostname }, (cookies: any) => {
    console.log(cookies);
   });
});



